# Extended Amidah or answering chazzan

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

Assuming one isn’t the 10th member of a minyan and is just a face in the crowd, if you have the option of praying a very slow and meaningful Amidah, but then you’ll end when the Chazan is already well into the chazara and will have missed answering amen to all those brachot (as well as kedusha), vs praying a regular paced Amidah with not as much kavanah in order to finish in time to answer all the chazan’s berachot, which option would be better?

In short, can I extend my personal Amidah even though it’ll make me miss kedusha and some of the chazzan’s berachot in the chazara?

Comment: Shomea k'one so you can always stop and listen to kedusha and be yotze without interrupting your own amida

Comment: @Dude That's bedieved, when there's no possibility of answering.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.109.1.1

Comment: @shmosel when you are in the middle of your amida you cannot answer so this becomes the only option if the chazan gets to kedusha before you finish.

Comment: @Dude Sure, but that doesn't clarify whether it should be avoided lechatchila.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Yalkut Yosef (90:43) [writes](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_all.html#HtmpReportNum0090_L2):

> מי שמאריך בתפלתו לצורך הכוונה, [וכגון שהצבור ממהרים, והוא מכוין כוונה
> הכרחית בביאור המלים, או מי שהוא עוסק בקבלה ורגיל לכוין כוונות
> וייחודים], ועל ידי זה מפסיד עניית קדושה, רשאי לעמוד בתפלת שמונה עשרה
> כשהצבור נמצא באמצע ברכת אמת ויציב, בכדי שיוכל להספיק להגיע לקדושה עם
> גמר תפלתו, וזה יותר נכון ממה שימהר בתפלתו, דאתי למיטרד, ויש בזה עירבוב
> הכוונה, ואפשר גם כן שיבואו לבלע את הקודש בהבלעת תיבות ואותיות. והקדמת
> שתים או שלש ברכות בלבד מותרת, מאחר שרוב תפלתו היא עם הצבור. **ומכל
> מקום אין הכרח לעשות כן, ורשאי להתחיל ביחד עם הצבור. ואם יפסיד מלענות
> קדושה או קדיש מפני שעדיין הוא נמצא באמצע תפלתו, אין בכך כלום, שהרי
> אנוס הוא.** ועל כל פנים בתפלת מנחה אינו רשאי להקדים תפלתו, שאין להקדים
> ולהתפלל לפני הקדיש, שאדרבה הקדיש עדיף יותר מהקדושה

Essentially, you have the option of starting Shemoneh Esrei before everyone else (when the minyan is saying emes v'yatziv) in order to finish in time for Kedusha. If that does not work, Rav Ovadia says that it is permitted to daven and whatever happens happens since it is considered an oness.

Comment: This is interesting because I was always under the impression that beginning גאל ישראל with the tzibbur was the ikar of like the entire tefilah, but he’s saying that kedusha is more important. Also, how can it be אנוס if it’s like a constant thing- like if it’s a one time thing it makes sense that it’s אנוס, but if you’re going into it knowing you’ll extend your Amidah, how can that be אנוס? Very interesting teshuva by Chacham

Comment: @CuriousYid It's better start amidah with the minyan, but I think most opinions don't require it.